# reduce space between elements in plot_summs

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to "shrink" the white space in the plot - I need those two coefficients closer to each other. How can I do this?

I use this code:

```
library(jtools)
library(ggplot2)

states <- as.data.frame(state.x77)
fit1 <- lm(Income ~ Frost + Illiteracy + Murder +
             Population + Area + `Life Exp` + `HS Grad`,
           data = states, weights = runif(50, 0.1, 3))
p <- plot_summs(fit1, 
                coefs = c("Frost Days" = "Frost", "% Illiterate" = "Illiteracy"),
                scale = TRUE)
p + 
  geom_text(aes(label = round(estimate)), vjust=-1)+
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are three options to get rid of the excess space between the lines:

1. Reduce the vertical dimension of your plotting window
2. Keep the plotting window the same size but reduce the height of the plot within the plotting window
3. Keep the plotting window and plot the same size but reduce the space between the lines

Here's how to do each one:

---

**1. Reduce the vertical dimension of your plotting window**

If you simply drag your window to make it less tall, your plot becomes:

[image]

---

**2. Reduce the height of the plot within the plotting window**

If you want to do this programmatically without changing your plot output size, you can set `aspect.ratio` in `theme`:

```r
p + 
  geom_text(aes(label = round(estimate)), vjust=-1)+
  theme(legend.position = "none", aspect.ratio = 1/4)
```

[image]

Though now of course you just have more white space *around* the plot.

---

**3. Reduce the space between the lines**

If you want the lines closer togther without reduing the dimensions of the axes etc, you can do:

```r
p + 
  geom_text(aes(label = round(estimate)), vjust=-1)+
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(2, 1))
```

[image]

Though of course, you now have lots of wasted space on either side of your lines.

---

In my opinion, the first option is by far the most aesthetic, professional and sensible.